# Values not showing in android recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in my project and data not bind to the recyclerview. I am getting data from the server and data correctly come. I put a Toast in the Adapter Class and it is working. I cannot figure out the problem.

Activity Class....

```
public class ViewDealerCompln extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_dealer_complain);

        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "productsans.ttf");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.com_recyclerView);

        compList = new ArrayList<>();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.com_view_app_bar);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        mTitle.setText("Complain History");
        mTitle.setTypeface(typeface);

        repID = DealerListAdapter.getRepID();
        dealerID = DealerListAdapter.getDealerID();

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adcAdapter);

        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {

        String tag_string_req = "req_data";

        request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_JSON_GETCOMPLAIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("feed")) {
                        JSONArray jsonFeedArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feed");
                        if (jsonFeedArray.length() > 0) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonFeedArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject currentObject = jsonFeedArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String namemm = currentObject.getString("compId");
                                compList.add(namemm);
                            }
                            adcAdapter = new ViewDealerComplainAdapter(ViewDealerCompln.this, compList);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data Available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Response from the server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

        };

    }

}
```

Adapter class...

```
public class ViewDealerComplainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewDealerComplainAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> subList;
    private Context context;

    public ViewDealerComplainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> a) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.subList = a;
        Toast.makeText(context, subList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_complain_list_row, parent, false);
        ViewDealerComplainAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder = new ViewDealerComplainAdapter.ItemViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(subList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subList.size();
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.compHID);
        }
    }
}
```

custom row layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/compHID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

main layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/com_view_app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar_send_complain"></include>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/com_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, before this line recyclerView.setAdapter(adcAdapter);
write

```
adcAdapter=new ViewDealerComplainAdapter(this,new ArrayList<String>())
```

In the adapter create a function as follow

```
public void setData(ArrayList<String> data){
this.sublist=data;
}
```

Now, in the function getData()
after this

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonFeedArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject currentObject = jsonFeedArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String namemm = currentObject.getString("compId");
                                compList.add(namemm);
                            }
```

write

```
adcAdapter.setData(compList);
adcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will make give you the result right as rain

Comment: i had to put **notifyItemRangeChanged(0, data.size());** in **setData()** method in the adapter.

Comment: yup, that would work if you dont wanna call adcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you setData

Answer (score 0):

after the loading data from the server update RecyclerView

```
   adcAdapter = new ViewDealerComplainAdapter(ViewDealerCompln.this, compList);
   adcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**another way**

create a method in Adapter

```
public void setDataChange(List<Object> asList) {
        this.List = asList;
        //now, tell the adapter about the update
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and

```
adcAdapter.setDataChange(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you have set the adapter before creating object.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adcAdapter);
getData();
```

You have first set the adapter to recyclerView and then you call getData() method in which you create object of adcAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

your adapter has two parameters context & arrayList, so while creating instance of adapter make sure you are passing both the values to adapter and set the same adapter to your RecyclerView.

mAdapter=new MAdapter(this,list);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

once you have data in your list then pass that list to adapter.

Answer (score -2):

You are setting `adcAdapter` in to `recyclerView` before initialize it.

Change code as blow.

```
adcAdapter = new ViewDealerComplainAdapter(ViewDealerCompln.this, compList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adcAdapter);
```

Also you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter to update recycleview when you get response.

```
 adcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Since the OP is making a network request it will probably finish and create a new adapter after your `setAdapter` has been called